# How can I calculate the length of any number if it starts with 0?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In this my python program. If I enter any number starting from zero, it gives me the wrong length of that number.

```
num = int(input("Enter any number to find out it's length: "))

def num_counter(any_num):
    """ function to count the number of int in a number """
    counter = 0
    while any_num > 0:
        any_num = any_num // 10
        counter += 1
    return counter

print(num_counter(num))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `int('01')` returns `1`.

`input` already returns a string, so you can use `len` to get the length of the string:

```
num = input("Enter any number to find out its length: ")
print(len(num))
```